# How to change font Navigation Drawer header and ScrollingActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, themes, material-design, navigation-drawer

How to change font Navigation Drawer title (header) ? 
It is right that could be easy with TextView but what about Scrolling Activity **if you have TextView in ScrollingActivity it wont work well**, how could I have TextView in ScrollingActivity and how could I change font without any TextView.

Thank you.